# J2ME - Using web services

Tags: java, java-me, jaxm

Does any one know how to use jaxm in j2me ?

Comment: I've worked with it some....but I don't see the question.

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't -- JAXM classes are not a required part of any J2ME profile. [JSR 172](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=172) details what you are talking about but I don't know of a phone that actually supports it. But it would be what you are looking for.

Comment: JSR 172 is available on all recent Nokia/SonyEricsson/Samsung Series60 phones. I suspect it's also available on all recent SonyEricsson feature phones. Very easy to add to a phone since Sun's reference implementation is pure Java.